# Running Python Script from VBA doesn't work because of file path embeded within the script, but the script runs fine on Pycharm

Tags: python, vba, os.path

I'm using VBA to run a python script that contains the following code, but it's not working:

```
path_to_current_dir = os.getcwd()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(path_to_current_dir, 'Analysis.xlsx'), engine='xlsxwriter')
```

But when I type the entire path in the Python script using the raw "r", VBA executes fine:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\...\A.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
```

I'm wondering how to get the first code to work since I'm trying to avoid hardcoding the path?

Thanks!

Comment: what does `os.path.join(path_to_current_dir, 'Analysis.xlsx'` produce as a string? Have you validated it? You will need '/' as your separator.

Comment: Yes, I validated that and it gets me the same exact path as the one in the second code piece. I also tried changing the '\' with '/' using the replace method but still get the same outcome

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: Nope, but I just did a second check using a print statement. I printed the file path when I’m running the script using VBA, and for some reason the path is defaulting to my documents and not using the current path generated by the os.path.join(path_to_current_dir, 'Analysis.xlsx'). I’m still note sure how to change this default or why it’s even happening when VBA is used

Comment: Are there any spaces in the filepath?

Comment: Also, if you are calling this via vba from shell I assume documents is the current directory and thus that is being picked up. So you would need to change the directory in the command line string or set the directory to work with via python.

Comment: There are no spaces in the file path. But you are right in terms of what I'm doing. I'm calling the script via vba from shell. I'm not sure how to change that cause I assumed when I changed the directory in the python script it would work but that wasn't the case. The script is still working in shell when I hard code the path in python but doesn't work when I use the relative path. Any idea how can I alter the relative one to avoid having it default to my documents?